# displaying dates of entire week starting day as saturday

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have got the code in this site for all weeks in a year as follows,i should populate week dates, starting date as saturday and end date as friday. when the week is finished it should enter to the next week with dates.
how could i achieve this please help me.

```
   DECLARE @Year INT=2013;  
  DECLARE @start DATE;  
 --DECLARE @WK INT=2  
 SET @start = DATEADD(YEAR, @Year-1900, 0);  

  ;WITH n AS  
  (  
  SELECT TOP (366) -- in case of leap year  
  TDate = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)-1, @start)  
  FROM sys.all_objects          
  ),  
   x AS  
  (  
  SELECT md = MIN(TDate) FROM n  
  WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, TDate) = 7 -- assuming DATEFIRST is SATURDAY  
  ),  
  y(TDate,wk) AS   
  (  
  SELECT n.TDate,  ((DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,n.TDate)-                                         
  DATEDIFF(DAY, @start,x.md)-1)/7)+1  
  FROM n CROSS JOIN x  
  WHERE n.TDate >= x.md  
  AND n.TDate < DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @start)  
  )  
  SELECT [date] = TDate, [week] = wk
  FROM y WHERE wk < 53
  ORDER BY [date];
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, what output do you expect? And have you considered using a [calendar table](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html) instead of a complex query? Or is this intended to populate a calendar table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what you're asking, but based on your query above this will give week numbers, based on Saturday being the first day of the week, for 2013:

```
DECLARE @Year INT=2013;  
DECLARE @start DATE;  

SET @start = DATEADD(YEAR, @Year-1900, 0);  

SET DATEFIRST 6; -- Set start of week as Saturday

WITH n AS  
(  
SELECT TOP (366) -- in case of leap year  
TDate = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)-1, @start)  
FROM sys.all_objects          
)
select TDate
  , DATEPART(WEEK,TDate)
from n
where year(TDate) = 2013;
```

**Edit:**

So based on the various comments and answers I *think* what is required here is, for a given day, return all days in that same week, with Saturday as the first day of the week. So something like this:

```
set datefirst 6; -- make sure first day of week is Saturday

declare @date date = getdate(); -- change date as required here

with daysOfWeek as
(
  select [date] = dateadd(dd, -datepart(dw, @date) + 1, @date)
  union all
  select [date] = dateadd(dd, 1, [date])
  from daysOfWeek
  where [date] < dateadd(dd, -datepart(dw, @date) + 7, @date)
)
select [date], dayOfWeek = datename(dw, [date])
from daysOfWeek
```

Which gives results:

[image]

I think this is what's required here?

**Second edit:**

First, create the function:

```
create function dbo.weekDates (@date date)
returns @dates table ([date] date, [dayofweek] varchar(9))
as
begin

  with daysOfWeek as
  (
    select [date] = dateadd(dd, -datepart(dw, @date) + 1, @date)
    union all
    select [date] = dateadd(dd, 1, [date])
    from daysOfWeek
    where [date] < dateadd(dd, -datepart(dw, @date) + 7, @date)
  )
  insert into @dates ([date], [dayofweek])
  select [date], [dayOfWeek] = datename(dw, [date])
  from daysOfWeek;

  return

end

go
```

Using the function:

```
set datefirst 6 -- Set Saturday as first day of week
select * from dbo.weekDates (getdate()) -- Change input parameter as required
```

Comment: I HAVE ACHIEVED TO DISPLAY THE WEEK DATES BUT IT IS DISPLAYING THE NEXT WEEK DATES I WAN T TO DISPLAY THE CURRENT WEEK DATES.

Comment: Please see the above edit. If this is still not correct you *really* need to post what output you require for a specific input.

Comment: the last code is helpful but how it could be achieved through function

Answer (score 0):

I HAVE ACHIEVED TO DISPLAY THE WEEK DATES BUT IT IS DISPLAYING THE NEXT WEEK DATES I WANT TO DISPLAY THE CURRENT WEEK DATES, HERE START DAY IS SATURDAY AND END DAY IS FRIDAY

```
ALTER FUNCTION GetCurrentWeek()
    RETURNS @TWeek TABLE (TWeek NVARCHAR(20))
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @Year INT= DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE());
    DECLARE @start DATE;
    SET @start = DATEADD(YEAR, @Year-1900, 0);

   ;WITH n AS
   (
    SELECT TOP (366) -- in case of leap year
    TDate = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)-1, @start)
    FROM sys.all_objects
    ),
    x AS 
    (
   SELECT md = MIN(TDate) FROM n 
   WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, TDate) = 7 -- assuming DATEFIRST is SATURDAY
   ),
   y(TDate,wk) AS
   (
   SELECT n.TDate, ((DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, n.TDate) 
   -   DATEDIFF(DAY, @start, x.md)-1)/7)   + 1
  FROM n CROSS JOIN x
  WHERE n.TDate >= x.md
  AND n.TDate < DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @start)
  )
  INSERT  @TWeek
   SELECT [date] = TDate
   FROM y WHERE wk =DATEPART(wk, GetDate())
    ORDER BY [date];
    RETURN;

   END
```